# "Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable" Making a calculator

Tags: c#

Second post here, so I started my computing course recently and we are working on C# I have understood everything to far and we have our first project that we are supposed to work on, however I have been stumped here, I will show you the entire code for you to read, then I will break away at the bottom to the part which the error is found:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Calculator
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string number;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Number0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number = number + "0";
        CalcForm.Text = number;
    }

    private void Number1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number = number + "1";
        CalcForm.Text = number;
    }

    private void Number2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number = number + "2";
        CalcForm.Text = number;
    }

    private void Number3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number = number + "3";
        CalcForm.Text = number;
    }

    private void Number4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number = number + "4";
        CalcForm.Text = number;
    }

    private void Number5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number = number + "5";
        CalcForm.Text = number;
    }

    private void Number6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number = number + "6";
        CalcForm.Text = number;
    }

    private void Number7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number = number + "7";
        CalcForm.Text = number;
    }

    private void Number8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number = number + "8";
        CalcForm.Text = number;
    }

    private void Number9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number = number + "9";
        CalcForm.Text = number;
    }

    private void ButtonDecimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        number = number + ".";
        CalcForm.Text = number;
    }

    private void ButtonTimes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string equation1 = CalcForm.Text;
        double equation1int = Convert.ToDouble(equation1);
        CalcForm.Text = "";
        number = "";
        string equation2 = CalcForm.Text;
        double equation2int = Convert.ToDouble(equation2);
        var equalsclicked = ButtonEquals_Click;
        if (equalsclicked == true) 
        {
        CalcForm.Text = "";
        number = "";
        double answer = equation1int * equation2int;
        string answer1 = Convert.ToString(answer);
        CalcForm.Text = answer1;
    }
    }

    private void ButtonEquals_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

So, there is the form code, and here is the error, I will comment on the exact line

```
{
    string equation1 = CalcForm.Text;
    double equation1int = Convert.ToDouble(equation1);
    CalcForm.Text = "";
    number = "";
    string equation2 = CalcForm.Text;
    double equation2int = Convert.ToDouble(equation2);
    var equalsclicked = ButtonEquals_Click; //Here
    if (equalsclicked == true) //Here
    {
    CalcForm.Text = "";
    number = "";
    double answer = equation1int * equation2int;
    string answer1 = Convert.ToString(answer);
    CalcForm.Text = answer1;
}
```

There are the errors, is there anything else that you can see wrong with it? Or optimization wise? This is only for multiplication, but once I have done that, I can easily copy it over, thanks :)

Comment: What is the purpose behind this line? `var equalsclicked = ButtonEquals_Click;`.  It doesn't really make any sense... you are looking for a true/false result from an event handler that is `void`?

Comment: Right, this is where I am going wrong, what I am aiming is for the if statement to run, when the button Equals is clicked, inside the if statement will be the final calculation.

Comment: To check if the ButtonEquals was pressed you could check the sender of the event.

Comment: You already have an event handler called ButtonEquals_Click which should be executed when they click on the appropriate button.  Why would any of that code be inside the ButtonTimes_Click event handler?

Comment: You also have an unclosed curly brace after your `if (equalsclicked == true)` statement.

Comment: I've been brought up to believe that for the string equation1 to be assigned in the code, it has to be in the same block of code, and our teacher said the easiest way to bypass this for now is to load it all into the same block.

Answer (score 1):

The error is exactly as the compiler says. You cannot use `var` when initializing with a method group. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx), with my emphasis:

> var can only be used when a local variable is declared and initialized in the same statement; the variable cannot be initialized to null, or to a **method group** or an anonymous function.

In your code, `ButtonEquals_Click` is a method group.

You have to explicitly state the type of the variable if you wish to initialize it with a method group.

However, it's fairly obvious that you do not really want to assign a method group to a local variable. Exactly what you are trying to do, I cannot discern from here.

It looks to me like you have not quite grasped event driven programming. You need to wait until the user clicks the button, and then respond to that button click in the event handler. The thing to learn about event handlers is that the system calls them, and you do not.

So, perhaps what you need to do is move the code inside the if statement into the `ButtonEquals_Click` event handler. You'll still have plenty of compiler errors when you do that, but it's a step in the right direction.

The next step for you, I think, is to try to understand event driven programming a bit more. Start from an empty project and add a couple of buttons. Add click event handlers that do different things. For example, they might call `MessageBox.Show` with different messages. Then run the program and click on the buttons. Note that the button event handlers only execute when the user clicks the button. Then take a look at your code. Notice how your code does nothing in the `ButtonEquals_Click` event handler, but is attempting to some how invoke that event from `ButtonTimes_Click`. Make sure that you fully understand that events are invoked by the framework in response to user input before you proceed.

Comment: Sorry, I might have been a little ambiguous what I am aiming to achieve, is for when the button equals is clicked, I aim for it to run the IF statement so that the final calculation can be completed.

Comment: I'll try that, however that has always brought me to the not in current context error, which I have never found a fix for apart from putting it into the same block of code.

Comment: If you need information to be available in both event handlers, you'll have to find a way to make it available to both. I tried to explain why you got the error message. I cannot write the rest of your program  for you. Your fundamental problem is that you have not yet fully grasped event driven programming. That's what you need to get on top of next.

Comment: Thank you, this is a bigger thing than what I first thought, however you could see where I was going? But I realized that due to this error, I can no longer repeat this method with the other operators, so I will have to figure a alternate route around this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a more complex project then you are thinking it is.  When the user clicks the times (multiplication) button you cannot yet calculate the result because they have yet to supply the second operand.

If the user enters "100" and then hits the multiplication button, how can you calculate anything?

When they hit multiply you must store the value they entered as the "old" value, clear the text, and remember the fact that they clicked multiply by using an enum variable.  Then later when they perform the next operation (such as clicking the equals sign), you would perform the operation on the old value with the current value (in this case, old value * new value) and store the result in the old value.

Comment: I think I need to go back a little, right now I am using all we got at our disposal, which our teacher said we needed and this is seems a little overboard, however it makes sense and I just need to understand it.

Comment: Thank you, and one last question for now, until a screw up later down the line, what is the easiest way for me to learn enum variables? It's a totally new term here, this would be my 4th week in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Think of your program as an event-based program. Every functions are basically event handlers, and as I can see that you handle correctly for all number buttons click event and decimal button click event. However, in the event handler ButtonTimes_Click(), you did it wrong as David has pointed out.

My suggestion is that in ButtonTimes_Click(), you will store operators (which are equation1 and equation2 in your codes). Then in ButtonEquals_Click(), you will do the multiply based on operators that are saved before and assign the result back to CalcForm.Text then clear operators.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, two questions: how would I work about getting the second equation stored easily? How would I then make the equals work for the other operators, would it be a simple if statement?

Comment: First, define equation1 and equation2 outside of the ButtonTimes_Click handler. They should be in class scope. Initially, equation1 is set to empty. In ButtonTimes_Click, you will check if equation1  is already assigned with text. If not then assign CalcForm.Text to equation1 and clear CalcForm.Text. Otherwise,  assign CalcForm.Text to equation2. Then in ButtonEquals_Click(), convert equation1 and equation2 to double, then multiply them and reset equation1, equation2, and CalcForm.Text to empty string.
Please be noticed that I assume that your program just do simple multiply on 2 numbers.

Comment: This is just the multiplication part, it is a full blown calculator, which is where I don't think that will work.

Comment: Definitely you need more work than just this to get a full calculator worked. Hope you get the idea of event driven programming.